# Make a timestamp variable persistent in ansible

Tags: ansible

I use Ansible to create and delete AWS launch configurations. I add the timestamp in the name. 
My problem is that, I can create the LC, but when it comes to deletion, the timestamp changes and then the playbook of deletion can't find the LC to delete it.
this is how I use the timestamp variable:
I put this in a file called timestamp_lc.yml:

```
- set_fact: now="{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }}"
```

and in the playbooks I call it:

```
- include: timestamp_lc.yml
```

How to make the variable `now` persistent so that ansible does not execute the date command every  time I call the variable `now` ?

this is the creation task:

```
- name: Create launch configuration
  sudo: yes
  command: >
    aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration
    --region {{ asg.region }}
    --launch-configuration-name "{{ asg.launch_configuration.name }}_{{ now }}"
```

The deletion task:

```
- name: Delete launch configuration
  sudo: yes
  command: >
    aws autoscaling delete-launch-configuration
    --region {{ asg.region }}
    --launch-configuration-name {{ asg.launch_configuration.name }}_{{ now }}
```

Comment: What do you want the deletion to do, exactly? Delete the LC with the highest timestamp? Delete the LC that was created last? Delete the LC that was created last from this machine? Delete the LC that was created last from this copy of the Ansible playbook repository?

Comment: delete the LC with the provided name that has the timestamp in it

Comment: But which timestamp?

Comment: the same timestamp that is used when the LC was created. if I create LC_201903132322 I want to delete LC_201903132322 (with the same timestamp )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will happen with every execution of the ansible as you are getting the value from the date command and setting a fact of that and that keeps on updating with every iteration.

One way I can think is to save the value in a file in an extension on the target server or the local server -- I feel this would be more reliable

```
---
- name: test play
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: checking the file stats
      stat:
        path: stack_delete_info
      register: delete_file_stat

    - name: tt
      debug:
        var: delete_file_stat

    - name: test
      shell: echo "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }}" > stack_delete_info
      when: delete_file_stat.stat.exists == false
```